# Как правильно выполнить функцию после Mysql операции?

Tags: golang, golang-faq

Здравствуйте.
Возникла такая проблема, есть запрос:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_Id=?", userId)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Потом делаю так:

```
    for rows.Next() {
    var user_Id string
    if err := rows.Scan(&user_Id); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Моя логика примерно такая. Я делаю поиск колонки user_Id в таблице users с данными userId который я получил раньше. Если нету совпадений, то мне нужно сделать запись в БД. Как делать запись я знаю, но как правильно сделать проверку, я не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен:3

Comment: Не понятна суть проблемы. Если нужна уникальность, почему не использовать индекс уникальности? Если `user_Id` первчный ключ, то он и так уникален и создать новый не получится - достаточно отловить ошибку. Если всё таки нужно проверить наличие то почему не используется `QueryRow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут слегка неправильно, если вам надо одну запись, надо использовать QueryRow.Scan(). Он вернёт err равный sql.ErrNoRows если записи нет, или nil если запись есть, или любую другую ошибку.